# Getting wrong layout

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dalvik

I decided to redo the homescreen for my application, so the first thing I did was to remove the specific landscape/portrait layouts and to use a simpler one. I also changed a GridView to a ListView (I changed their id's, too). The problem is that, after adapting everything and giving it a try, I started getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to use the newer ListView.

After using the emulator and `hierarchyviewer`, I saw that, miraculously, it was inflating the previous layout, even after physically deleting it.

So, after 2 hours trying to figure out what kind of black sorcery was going on, I decided to start a new homescreen from scratch, calling it welcomescreen (so, no references to the previous activity or layout were there). I deleted the previous one and told the `AndroidManifest` to pick this new activity.

After installing the application into my phone, like magic, it loaded a completely different (yet still present into my layout's folder) view. As a coincidence, it loaded the layout that was just above the one I wanted in the R file.

Has anyone happened to see and solve this weird problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should post some code.  Your description is confusing.

Comment: Post some code and give us the logcat for the exception that you're getting.

Comment: Remember that you can't clean your project to many times ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This often happens to me after creating a new string resource, or deleting one.  I think ADT has a bug that occasionally occurs, where it doesn't realize you've changed the number of resources, so everything after the new or deleted resources gets its ID offset by one.

Going to Project--->Clean... fixes it for me every time.

Another possible issue you could have is if you were updating a layout's ids, but forgot to update them in one of the configurations, such as layout-large or layout-land. The compiler won't complain about this, so you have to watch carefully for it.

Comment: Amazing! It worked like a charm. Looks like the precompiled stuff isn't well updated, isn't it? Something to me happened adding a drawable which started with numbers. It seems to be ok to the filesystem, though not when written to R (vars can't start with a number, so it isn't created correctly). So at that moment, Android was showing drawables which were not the correct ones. Cool anyway, thanks!